# Key-Value-Observation -- Looking for a more elegant solution to respond to value changes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, cocoa, key-value-observing

I've run into a frustrating feature of KVO: all notifications are funneled through a single method (`observeValueForKeyPath:....`), requiring a bunch of IF statements if the object is observing numerous properties.

The ideal solution would be to pass a method as an argument to the method that establishes the observing in the first place, but it seems this isn't possible. Does a solution exist to this problem? I initially considered using the `keyPath` argument (`addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:`) to call a method via `NSSelectorFromString`, but then I came across the post [KVO Dispatcher pattern with Method as context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566922/kvo-dispatcher-pattern-with-method-as-context) and the article it linked to which offers a different solution in order to pass arguments along as well (although I haven't gotten that working yet).

I know a lot of people have come up against this issue. Has a standard way of handling it emerged?

Comment: There are multiple different implementations of block-based KVO out there, which you can find with a simple google.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa is one particularly novel approach to making value-change observations less clunky.

Answer (score 1):

OP asks:

> Has a standard way of handling it emerged?

No, not really. There are a lot of different approaches out there. Here are some:

- https://github.com/sleroux/KVO-Blocks
- http://pandamonia.github.io/BlocksKit
- http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-03-02-key-value-observing-done-right-take-2.html
- https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa
- http://blog.andymatuschak.org/post/156229939/kvo-blocks-block-callbacks-for-cocoa-observers
- Seriously, there are a ton of these... [Google "KVO blocks"](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=KVO%20blocks)

I can't say that any of the options I've seen seem prevalent enough to earn the title "standard way". I suspect most folks who feel motivated to conquer this issue just pick one and go with it, or write their own -- it's not as if adapting KVO to use block based callbacks is rocket science.  The Method-based approach you link to doesn't seem like a step forward for simplicity. I get that you're trying to take the uncertainty of the string-based-key-path <-> method conversion out of the equation, but that kind of falls down because not all observable keys/keyPaths are methods. (If nothing else, you can observe arbitrary keys on NSMutableDictionaries and get notifications.)

It sure would be nice if Apple would release a new blocks-based KVO API, but I'm not holding my breath. But in the meantime, like I said, just pick one you like and use it or write your own and use that.